# Request Cookies Returns Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, server

I have been stocked into this for quite a while now. Whenever I pass this code

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const rf_token = "Hello Express Cookies";
  res.cookie("refreshtoken", rf_token, {
    httpOnly: true,
      path: "/api/users/refresh_token",
      maxAge: 7 * 24,
  });

  console.log("refresh_token: ", req.cookies.refreshtoken);
});
```

**Sadly, this is what it returns**

```
refresh_token:  undefined
```

I read through some solutions provided here but it seems not to run for me

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/api/users", userRouter);
```

I initialized cookie-parser before my route.

I installed the cookie-parser using `npm install cookie-parser --save`

This is the actual code of where the bug is found

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "This email does not exist." });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password do not match." });

    const getRefreshToken = createRefreshToken({ id: user._id });

    res.cookie("getrefreshtoken", getRefreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      path: "/api/users/refresh_token",
      maxAge: 7 * 24,
    });

    res.json({ message: "You have successfully logged in!" });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

This is where I try requesting for the token

```
exports.theToken = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const refresh_token = req.cookies.getrefreshtoken;

    console.log(refresh_token);

    if (!refresh_token)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Please login now!" });

    jwt.verify(refresh_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (error, user) => {
      if (error) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Please login now!" });

      const access_token = createAccessToken({ id: user.id });
      res.json({ access_token });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

`createRefreshToken` and `createAccessToken` are functions that pass user data to get a JSON web token.

In the client-side, it returns 400 error only to find out that in the server nothing is being sent to the client because it returns undefined

Comment: try catching the error with 'try-catch' block.

Comment: I just did now and it still returns undefined without any error in the server console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges here.

Calling `res.cookie()` sets a `Set-Cookie` header in the response that will be sent back with your response when you send the response and the client is then responsible for saving that newly set cookie.

Examining `res.cookies` looks at the already parsed incoming cookies from the request headers that have already arrived and already been parsed.  So, what you do in `res.cookie()` will not show up the same request's `res.cookies`.  You could examine the outgoing headers and see that `res.cookie()` put a new `Set-Cookie` header there.

You should see your value show up in `res.cookies` on the next incoming request from that client (assuming that client is supporting cookies).

---

FYI, the code you show for your `/` route never sends any response so the cookie you set never gets actually sent out either.  You need a `res.send(...)` or a `res.json(...)` or something like that to actually send a response that the cookie you configured can go with.

Also, since it looks like you're setting an explicit path on that cookie, the browser will only ever send that cookie with a request to that specific path too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited this question can you check it out again?

Comment: @OgeObubu - I think I explained the answer to your original question.  It is not the way of Stackoverflow to change your question to another question after answers have already been posted.  If you want to ask another question after this, then please accept this answer (since it answers your original question) and post a new question that explains what exactly the new question is and shows what debugging steps you took to try to diagnose it and then asks a very specific question about where you got stuck.

Comment: @OgeObubu - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your original question, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: @OgeObubu - If you ask a new question related to this topic, just leave me a comment here with a link to it and I'll take a look.